# Does Hawking radiation depend on the coordinate system used?

Tags: black-holes, coordinate-systems, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

First things first, this question is different from the one I posted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628006/problem-when-attempting-to-derive-hawking-temperature), the coefficients I've found in this link are wrong, but the right coefficients suffer from the same strange relation:

\begin{align}
|\alpha_{p,k;r_s,\infty}| &\propto |\omega_k+\omega_p|e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi\omega_p r_s}
\\
|\beta_{p,k;r_s,\infty}| &\propto |\omega_k-\omega_p|e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi\omega_p r_s}
\end{align}
With the same proportionality factor. So in the coordinate system I use, we don't have $|\alpha_{\omega,\omega'}|=e^{\pi\omega r_s}|\beta_{\omega,\omega'}|$

From [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0010055) (*An Introduction to Black Hole Evaporation*, Jennie Traschen) and from the original article of Hawking on his radiations, we can see that the tortoise coordinates and null coordinates/null Kruskal coordinates are used and then give the wright relation between the Bogoliubov coefficients.

In fact, it seems to me that the very structure of Bogoliubov coefficients can't give the relation $|\alpha_{\omega,\omega'}|=e^{\pi\omega r_s}|\beta_{\omega,\omega'}|$ in spherical coordinates, since in these we necessarily have $\Phi=e^{i\omega t}\phi(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\varphi)$.

So my question is: Is the Hawking radiation a coordinate dependent phenomenon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer is no**, the Hawking radiation is not a coordinate dependent phenomenon. These (Kruskal-Szekeres and Tortoise) coordinates simplify the problem significantly when you are dealing with QFT in curved spacetime background (here Schwarzschild black hole background). Physically, any static observer at infinity would detect the same Hawking radiation rate. This also can be verified by use of the explicit form of Hawking radiation in terms of surface gravity ($\kappa$), i.e.,

$${T_{\rm{H}}} = \frac{\kappa }{{2\pi }}\,\,{\rm{where}}\,\,\kappa  = \sqrt { - \frac{1}{2}({\nabla _\mu }{\xi _\nu })({\nabla ^\mu }{\xi ^\nu })}, $$
where $\xi _\nu$ is the Killing vector field satisfying the Killing equation, ${\nabla _\mu }{\xi _\nu } + {\nabla _\nu }{\xi _\mu } = 0$. Killing fields are the infinitesimal generators of isometries and each of them corresponds to a quantity which is conserved along geodesics. Obviously, this definition does not depend on the coordinates one is dealing with.

**To make it more clear:**

Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates have the advantage that they are well-behaved everywhere outside the physical singularity. In addition, they cover the entire spacetime manifold of the maximally extended Schwarzschild solution. For these reasons, KS coordinates which describes the entire spacetime are suitable for any observer freely falling through the horizon.

Tortoise coordinates are just suitable for a remote observer/frame at fixed location in black hole background since when an observer approaches a black hole event horizon, its Schwarzschild time coordinate grows infinite. The outgoing null rays in this coordinate system have an infinite change in $t$ on travelling out from the horizon. The tortoise coordinate is intended to grow infinite at the appropriate rate such as to cancel out this singular behavior in coordinate systems constructed from it.

Generally, in order to derive the Hawking temperature, you need to consider quantum fields from the viewpoints of different observers since there is no unique mode decomposition of the quantum fields. This is the main idea. The problem is to find the physical, well-behaved coordinates free from pathological properties. If you can construct such coordinates, you will find the same relation for the Hawking radiation.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I did not know about this formula for the temperature at any distance! However, I would like to know how to interpret the fact that when using not well-behaved coordinates, one cannot recover the right relation between the Bogoliubov coefficients.

Comment: I derived the Hawking and the Unruh effects a few years ago and I had almost the same problem as yours. I could convinced myself that these effects can be obtained by considering two appropriate (a static and a freely falling) frames. But, I think working with an ill-defined frame or any inappropriate (but, well-defined) frame would be a very hard exercise! Of course, most probably, you cannot recover the Hawking effect by an ill-defined frame. In such cases, I think the Bogolyubov transformations from one set of basis modes into another are ill-defined.

Comment: So, for example, if I want to use the solution given [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4823.pdf) (The Klein-Gordon equation in the spacetime of a
charged and rotating black hole, V. B. Bezerra, H. S. Vieira and A. A. Costa) together with the Bogoliubov coefficients methods, I will fail to derive the hawking temperature? This seems strange to me, but I think I have to learn more about the Bogoliubov transformation to have a strong opinion about all this.

Comment: I think the paper that you mentioned is far from our discussion. In the answer, I stated that "If you can construct such coordinates, you will find the same relation for the Hawking radiation."

Comment: The point is that different observers will decompose the quantum fields in different momentum modes. So, first you need to construct a static frame with respect to the black hole for a remote observer and then you need to determine an appropriate metric for a freely falling frame near/crossing the event horizon. These two coordinate frames must overlap outside the black hole's event horizon. Having this property, Bogolyubov transformations can be defined.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! From another article, I saw that when a solution is known, no need for a Bogoliubov transformation, there's another method.. I think you are right when you say that the Bogoliubov Transformation is ill-defined for an ill-defined coordinate system at the horizon: The field itself is ill-defined, as shown by the solutions I've found in my previous post I've linked, and by the article I gave you.

Comment: Yes, the Hawking radiation has been derived in many different ways and we here discussed about its traditional derivation. For example, this effect has been derived by use of the renormalized energy-momentum tensor of quantum field in black hole background. My favorite approach is the Euclidean field theory, in which, in the middle of evaluating the partition function of black hole, the black hole temperature (Hawking radiation) is found straightforwardly. In fact, this is the source of  Euclidean trick for obtaining the Hawking radiation. I'm sure there are other approaches.

Comment: "*the Hawking radiation is not a coordinate dependent phenomenon*" - Really? Does it exist in the raindrop coordinates? Based on the equivalence principle, the Hawking radiation is similar to the Unruh radiation. Is the Unruh radiation also "not a coordinate dependent phenomenon"? It sure doesn't exist in an inertial frame. I am not making any claims, but just wondering if you can share an expert insight.

Comment: @safesphere, Black hole metric (solution) is different from the black hole coordinates. For example, Schwarzschild metric is the only solution to the Einstein field equations in vacuum with spherical symmetry (Birkhoff's theorem). But, the Schwarzschild solution can be expressed in a range of different choices of coordinates besides the Schwarzschild coordinates, e.g. Eddington–Finkelstein coordinates, Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates, Tortoise coordinates etc. The subject of this discussion is about the different coordinates which cover/describe a certain black hole background.

Comment: @safesphere, To be more specific, in this discussion, we were talking about detecting Hawking radiation by a static, remote observer in a specific (Schwarzschild) black hole background. He/She would always detect the same value (for Schwarzschild case we always have ${T_{\rm{H}}} = \frac{\kappa }{{2\pi }} = \frac{1}{{8\pi M}}$, no doubt!). Physically, this means that all observers located at the rest far away from the black hole would detect the same Hawking radiation. However, they may choose different (appropriate) coordinates for describing the black hole spacetime.

Comment: @safesphere, And yes, Hawking temperature exists in the raindrop (Gullstrand–Painlevé) coordinates as well, the temperature is
same as the standard Hawking temperature. The explicit proof is here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/19/10/310/meta.